# Maximum safe clock frequency of full adder circuit

Tags: digital-logic, frequency

[image: Full adder circuit]

A full adder consists of 2 xor gates, 2 and and 1 or gate. The propagational delay of any of these logic gates is 8 ms. I have to find out the maximum safe clock frequency. As there are total 5 logic gates and 8 × 5 = 40 ms. f = 1 / t = 1 / 40 ms. Is it going to be the correct answer? Or am i making a mistake?

Comment: Sounds much like a school problem, but that's not necessarily a big deal. However, You'll get much better answers if you at least try to figure out a possible schematic for your adder and edit it into your question. Hint: Your five gates are probably not all in series, some might be parallel. What limits the max. frequency is a race condition between simultaneous signals you send along parallel paths that include different propagation delays, and a possible feedback of an output to an input...

Comment: Don't mean to be picky, but this is a purely asynchronous circuit; there is no clock.

Comment: As mentioned by user28910 talking about a clock only makes sense if you add flip flops in front of and behind the logic shown. Then you have a clock to output time, set up time and hold time to add in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum frequency is the worst-case delay for every gate wired in series. In your diagram, the carry output comes from the results of three gates, so `3 * 8ms = 24ms`.

Comment: What about sum? its also passes through 2 gates? so the time of sum should be included as well ?

Comment: @user1259768 What you need to look for is the longest path (in number of gates) for any possible input signal to any possible output signal. This is the critical path when it comes to timing. For your example, the carry will be valid after 3*tpd, and the sum will already be valid after 2*tpd. Put another way, the sum will say "I'm already here!" once the carry has finally decided if it prefers to be high or low.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, you might consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.